# JCalendar save date to different variables

Tags: java, netbeans, jcalendar

I would like to save the date that I chose with JCalendar in 3 variables. One for the day, month, and year. How is this possible, and how could I do it? I created my code with a JFrame in Netbeans, and with the design tools.

Comment: ... Why in three separate variables?  That's going to make it hard to work with (ie - do you know the formula for leap years?).  You'd be better off using a 'date' type, preferably something like the excellent [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library (because the standard JDK one sucks).

Comment: I would like to take for different classes only the day and year. It's just my program. So i want to save it in 3 variables or to save it in one variable and seperate it after that.

Comment: JodaTime supports a number of different composite fields.  Really, the best thing to do in general is keep it as a date/time/timestamp type, then just translate/format it at display time.  This is especially important when dealing with an international context, where formatting changes often.

Comment: I used JCalendar because i could create a diplay calendar to choose the date you want. So after this selection i just want to seperate it. I don't know if this is possible and how at JodaTime.